# Module name different from its Image File name

Tags: windows, windbg, portable-executable

So after debugging an executable on windbg, I noticed that the module name was different from the image name.

Upon first loading the executable and setting a breakpoint before the entry point, the `lm vm`/`!for_each_module` command shows this.

```
start    end        module name
00a30000 00a38000   Injection C (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: C:\Users\user\Downloads\Bird.exe
    Image path: Injection.exe
    Image name: Injection.exe
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Mon May 24 22:30:53 2021 (60AC0CFD)
    CheckSum:         00000000
    ImageSize:        00008000
```

As you can see above the `Image Name` field does not correspond to the `Loaded symbol image file` name.

Any idea why? Does it have to do with the `.pdb` file path?

I couldn't find any related info's about this in the PE format.

How could one go to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is mentioned that both those may differ significantly in docs for [lm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/lm--list-loaded-modules-) as well as [!for_each_module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-for-each-module)

infact !for_each_module has Two CommandStrings one being **@#ModuleName** and other being **@#ImageName**

i haven't looked much but sometimes i have seen replacements like foo_1480xxx etc

do you have a binary that is shareable which show this behavior

EDIT

just glanced through the file it appears the name of pdb file inside the binary
is Injection.pdb
and the executable has been  renamed after compilation

```
F:\Latebird>ls
LateBird.exe

F:\Latebird>file LateBird.exe
LateBird.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows

F:\Latebird>certutil -hashfile LateBird.exe sha1
943710a2a04caeae3ab21cc8be83ebc1d556e127
   
F:\Latebird>certutil -hashfile LateBird.exe md5
c8e3b7b9dc2541574335f9141e3ca4bf
   
F:\Latebird>dbh LateBird.exe

LateBird [1000000]: i


      ModuleName : LateBird
       ImageName : LateBird.exe
 LoadedImageName : F:\Latebird\LateBird.exe
   LoadedPdbName :
           CVSig : 0x53445352
          CVData : C:\Users\Dynamic\source\repos\Injection\Release\Injection.pdb

          PdbAge : 0xa
    PdbUnmatched : false

     MachineType : I386

LateBird [1000000]:
```

just to reconfirm I compiled a Messagebox and renamed it after compilation
loaded it windbg and checked lmvm

results below

```
ls -lg
total 17
-rwxr-xr-x 1 12800  LateBird.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1   165  LateBirdie.cpp

cat LateBirdie.cpp
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain (_In_ HINSTANCE,_In_opt_ HINSTANCE,_In_ LPSTR,_In_ int ){
    return MessageBoxA(NULL, "LateBirdie", "Early Birdie", 0);
}

cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /nologo LateBirdie.cpp /link /release user32.lib /entry:WinMain
LateBirdie.cpp

file LateBirdie.exe
LateBirdie.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows

ren LateBirdie.exe EarlyBirdie.exe

cdb -c ".reload /f; lmvm *bird*;q" EarlyBirdie.exe | awk "/Reading/,/quit/"
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.reload /f; lmvm *bird*;q'
Reloading current modules
start             end                 module name
00007ff6`87e50000 00007ff6`87e54000   LateBirdie     F:\Latebird\LateBirdie.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: F:\Latebird\EarlyBirdie.exe
    Image path: LateBirdie.exe
    Image name: LateBirdie.exe
    Timestamp:        Tue Jun  1 02:56:35 2021 (60B5548B)
    CheckSum:         0000FCA9
    ImageSize:        00004000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
    Information from resource tables:
quit:
```

Comment: Yep, here is the binary: https://filepost.io/d/LefYuiYd6e (link available for 10 days)

Comment: By the way, It's a capture the flag challenge so your AV might flag it as malware.